# (PHP) Get repeated data (MySQL) from a value in a dropdown list and show it in a table

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, show

I have a file that has a dropdown list with a set of values (matricula) from a database (movimentos) what I want is when I select that value in the dropdown list it searches the database for repeated rows and it shows it in a table with all the data from that value (it's currently 3 columns, "matricula,"marca" and "despesa")

Below is the code I use to get the value from the dropdown list, and this is where I have the problem, I can't get the value from the dropdown list to show the respective rows in the table.

```
 <a href='verificar.dwt.php'>Voltar atrás</a>

<div align="center"><? 

include 'configmov.dwt.php'; 

$tableName='movimentos';
$matricula = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matricula']);

$sql="SELECT matricula, marca, despesa FROM $tableName WHERE $matricula in (SELECT matricula FROM $tableName GROUP BY $matricula HAVING count($matricula) > 1)"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
$n=1; 

echo "Os seus resultados: <p>";

echo "<table border=0>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCFFCC'>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Matricula</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Marca</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Despesa</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<table border=0>";
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['matricula']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['marca']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['despesa']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

?>

</div>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>
```

I'm around this problem for a while and I did a lot of research before coming here to make this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are checking for an exact match in Table for the posted value, why cant you use this instead?

```
 $sql="SELECT matricula, marca, despesa FROM ".$tableName." WHERE matricula = '".$matricula."'";
```

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and it did the work!! Man i am so happy! really really thanks, my brain was malfuncting with this one

Comment: it was simple SQL, if you want to make the table a single one, make sure you change the table as i have given in my previous answer..

Comment: ive changed the table with you´re previous answer and everything works and looks good now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

First of all.. I think that your syntax is wrong.

Try this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT matricula, marca, despesa FROM '$tableName' WHERE '$matricula' in (SELECT matricula FROM '$tableName' GROUP BY '$matricula' HAVING count('$matricula') > 1)";
```

In a query you must put the php variables between quotes.

Comment: ive done what you said but it´s still not showing the value from the dropdown list, i may have something wrong

Answer (score 1):

matricula is a field from table, in your post... not a php variable..So you must have : 
 GROUP BY matricula HAVIG count(matricula)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you SQL syntax is correct and try this code for making a table from returned database values to make it a single table

```
echo "<table border=0>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCFFCC'>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Matricula</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Marca</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Despesa</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['matricula']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['marca']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['despesa']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```